# PDFsharp MigraDoc add runtime generated bitmap to table cell

Tags: c#, bitmap, pdfsharp, migradoc

I wanted to use PDFsharp and MigraDoc to generate PDFs. As far as now it all works perfectly.

Now I have come up with an idea to create a bitmap during runtime and add it to one of my table cells.

I've read that it is possible to add bitmaps from resource so, without having them on the harddrive.

See: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDoc_FilelessImages.ashx

This is my try to adapt it to my small project:

Code for creating the Bitmap:

```
Bitmap GreenDot = new Bitmap(32,32);
Graphics GreenDotGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(GreenDot);
GreenDotGraphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green,0,0,32,32);

//The next step will be converting the Bitmap to an byte[]

var byteGreenDot = ImageToByte(GreenDot);

//Now converting it to string as seen in the WikiPage

string stringGreenDot = Convert.ToBase64String(byteGreenDot);
string FinalGreenDot = "base64:"+ stringGreenDot;

//Now creating a table
.
.
.
cell = MyRow.Cell[1];
cell.AddImage(FinalGreenDot);
.
.
.
```

Code for converting bitmap to byte[]

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte(System.Drawing.Image img)
{
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        img.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

As I run the code I'll get a warning saying "warning: Image 'base64:Qk02E[...]==' not found." (the base64 string was truncated for this post).

I guess that I don't convert it correctly to byte[].

Can someone get me on the right track?

Comment: Isn't the data type of the first parameter of `AddImage()` defined as `string`? This would explain the error message as the image object is converted implicitly to string via `ToString()`. In this case you need to state a  filename rather than a stream (at least in my project i need to pass filenames).

Comment: Please read the linked Wiki article.

Comment: Yeah, and what does the article say? `section.AddImage(imageFilename);` - do you see the word `Filename` in the variable name? Thats why i wrote you need to pass a filename.

Comment: MigraDoc now accepts filenames that contain BASE64-encoded images with the prefix "base64:". In this case, the filename does not refer to a file, the filename contains all the bits of the bitmap in an ASCII string with the BASE64 encoding.
A byte array (byte[] in C#) can easily be converted to a filename. If you have a stream, you can easily read it into a byte array and use it.
However, thank you for your effort.

Comment: The BASE64 encoding was done correctly, but the warning shown in the original message was truncated in a misleading way, putting "BYTES" instead of the actual BASE64 data and thus giving a wrong impression (at least to me).

Comment: Yeah should have formatted it the way you have in the edit. Thank you.
Thought it was clear.

Answer (score -1):

Note that you are using a feature that was introduced with version 1.50.

When using version 1.32 or earlier, you get the warning you mention.

Your code works as expected when using version 1.50 beta 2 or later.

Comment: I'm using 1.50. This is why I wonder. 1.50.4589.0 to be precise.

Comment: I successfully tried those three NuGet packages: `PDFsharp-MigraDoc-WPF.1.50.4589-beta4`, `PDFsharp-MigraDoc-wpf.1.50.4619-beta4c`, and `PDFsharp-MigraDoc-wpf.1.50.4000-beta3b`. The Document Properties page in Adobe Reader shows which version was used to create a PDF.

Comment: I resetted everything restarted the machine and re-assigned the 1.50 dll which I used before and it is working. Maybe VS gone wild.
Thank you anyway. Good to know that my code was working from the beginning ;)